# jquery plugin zoom - thumbnail showing the original image. not the correct one

Tags: jquery, shopify

I'm using zoom jquery plugin from https://github.com/jackmoore/zoom and I am having issues zooming a different image from the thumbnail. It zoom the original image.

Please see video: https://www.useloom.com/share/0630cf4dd85d403081e1cfbd0443f34c

my jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.image-zoom')
  .css('display', 'block')
  .parent()
  .zoom({
    url: $('.image-zoom').attr('data-zoom')
  });
});
```

My guess the problem is the targeting of the correct image from `attr('data-zoom')`. How can I do that correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is because you are using a class to find your attr, and it returns all of them.  Using `this` should solve your problem.

```
$('.image-zoom')
    .css('display', 'block')
    .zoom({
        url: $(this).attr('data-zoom')
    });
```

By using `this`, we can stay in the scope of the current image.

Comment: thank you for your help but its still not working. I used " url: $(this).find('.image-zoom').attr('data-zoom')" please see video: https://www.useloom.com/share/92cb054b04e8408fa9fc3ecfcb606c94?focus_title=1&muted=1

Comment: @user2317589 can you please paste in your question the HTML structure of the zoom images?  I'm just guessing in the dark here!  Or chat me and I can take a better look

Comment: @user2317589 i have removed the `parent()` call, I believe that is what is causing problems.

Comment: Raccui , I removed the parent() and the zoom jquery is not longer working. Please see video: https://www.useloom.com/share/d714fc24c68441df8d15a01720d44fd2?focus_title=1&muted=1

Comment: I don't how to message you in here. Can you add me on skype please? jmcausing